# Probability of Die Equality

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You have 4 fair six-sided die. You roll all four once. What is the probability that any of them have the same number as any other of them?

In other words, what is the probability that $D_1=D_2$ or $D_1=D_3$ or $D_1=D_4$ or $D_2=D_3$ or $D_2=D_4$ or $D_3=D_4$ or some combination of those?

I have worked several small dimensional problems and cannot identify a pattern as the number of die increases or as the number of sides increases.

Comment: It is much easier to calculate the probability $p$ that they are all **different**.  Then the probability $2$ **or more** are the same is $1-p$. I assume you are going after the probability of $2$ or more.  If you want the probability two match and the others are different from the two, and from each other, it will have to be done another way. Not hard, but it would be good to know exactly the event whose probability you are after.

Answer (score 3):

**Calculate $1$ minus the probability of the complementary event:**

- The number of combinations containing $4$ different values is $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3=360$
- The number of combinations containing any $4$ values is $6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6=1296$
- So the probability of getting some identical values is $1-\frac{360}{1296}\approx72\%$